# Lemma 1.19 in Colding-Minicozzi

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, minimal-surfaces

The statement is as follows. See page 30 of [CM](https://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-121-prev.pdf) or below for an image of the proof.

> If $u:\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a solution to the minimal surface equation, then for all nonnegative Lipschitz functions $\eta$ with support contained in $\Omega\times \mathbb{R}$,
> $$\int_{\text{graph } u} |A|^2\eta^2\leq C\int_{\text{graph } u}|\nabla_{{\text{graph } u}}\eta|^2.$$

I understand the Lipschitz assumption, as that much regularity is sufficient for Stokes' theorem, and the logarithmic cutoff function they build in the next section is Lipschitz not differentiable. However, I'm not sure where the non-negative assumption is really used in the proof.

As far as I can tell, it's only used in the first inequality of (1.99), and one may just replace $\eta$ with $|\eta|$ and the same proof goes through.
[image]

**EDIT:** To hopefully address Ted Shifrin's comments, I'm not suggesting replacing $\eta$ with $|\eta|$ throughout, just in the RHS of the first inequality. Let me write out my proposed proof of (1.99) without any assumption on the sign of $\eta$.

By Stokes' and $\eta^2$ vanishing on $\partial \Sigma$, we know that
$$0=\int_\Sigma d(2\eta^2 N^*\alpha)=\int_\Sigma 4\eta d\eta\wedge N^*\alpha+\int_\Sigma 2\eta^2dN^*\alpha.$$
We therefore compute
\begin{align*}
    \int_\Sigma \eta^2|A|^2d\Sigma&=2\int_\Sigma\eta^2dN^*\alpha\\
    &=-4\int_\Sigma\eta d\eta \wedge N^*\alpha\\
    &\leq 4C\int_\Sigma |\eta| |\nabla_\Sigma \eta||A|d\Sigma\\
    &\leq 4C\left(\int_\Sigma \eta^2|A|^2d\Sigma\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_\Sigma |\nabla_\Sigma\eta|^2d\Sigma\right)^{\frac{1}{2}},
\end{align*}
and continue as CM. In particular, I don't think I'm differentiating $|\eta|$ anywhere in this proof.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but your “direct quotation” of the statement is mistyped and makes no sense. Make some efforts, in addition, to make your question self-contained.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, should be fixed now. I've also added in an image of the proof.

Comment: It certainly seems that $\eta\ge 0$ is being used to get the inequality with the (1.99) label on it.

Comment: Isn't that just applying norm to the $-4\int_\Sigma \eta d\eta\wedge N^*\alpha$ term then using triangle inequality and (1.98)? It does seem that you are using $\eta\geq 0$ to write $\eta$ on the RHS of the inequality, but surely you can just replace that term with $|\eta|$?

Comment: But differentiating $\eta$ and differentiating $|\eta|$ are very different. Write every step out.

Comment: I've made a clarifying edit to hopefully address the comment. Please let me know I've misinterpreted what you're saying!

Comment: By analogy with typical elliptic estimates, I'd assume this is true for any compactly supported $\eta$: apply the estimate to the positive and minus the negative parts of a sign-changing $\eta$ and add the results. Viewed from this perspective may also reveal why it was assumed $\eta$ is positive: it's essentially without loss of generality, and is probably the useful case to the authors.

Comment: By "typical elliptic estimate" I guess you're referring to Sobolev inequality? And yes, the immediate application is to a compactly supported, non-negative Lipschitz cutoff function. I just wanted a sanity check to confirm that the non-negativity assumption is superfluous.